# How to solve algo trading bug

Tags: debugging, knapsack-problem

Following a course on algorithmic trading on python. However, 20 minutes in, run a command and get this. Please help. tried everything [the code i ran](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQjWo.png). Everything is updated and I have tried everything. The program I am running it on is Jupyter notebook

Comment: The error is telling you a lot. What did you try? Be more specific than 'everything'. Also, please read ['How do I ask a good question?'](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and pay special attention to the bulleted point 'DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.—'). The language should probably be in the topic tags, too. As to the possible issue and why I say the error is telling you a lot. Packages change over time and un-updated course materials don't always reflect those changes. Partly because one of the things you should be learning is how to troubleshoot as well.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.